# How to implement tinyurl on grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails3

How to implement tinyurl on grails 3?

Or can someone suggest the implementing code of the same plugin which was available in grails 2

Comment: Why not using tinyurl grails plugin?

Comment: grails 3 does not support tinyurl plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could upgrade the plugin to grails 3, if you really need it.  However, the TinyURL API appears to be pretty straightforward: make a GET call and read the response.

Example:

```
"http://example.com/api-create.php?url=http://google.com/".toURL().text
```

In this case "example" should be replaced with tinyurl, but I cannot post that here because tinyurl links are blocked in SO answers.

Comment: Thanks for the response i have not upgraded the plugin but created a service with this